# Error: The WebResource.axd handler must be registered in the configuration to process this request

Tags: iis-7, webresource.axd

I have created a simple application with 1 textbox, 1 button and a validator control. When I deploy it to the Windows server 2008, I get the following error.

The WebResource.axd handler must be registered in the configuration to process this request.

I have added the following handler  but it still gives the same exception. If I remove the validator control, then it works fine.

```
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="Foo" path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET"
             type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

I have searched online but haven't found any solution. has anyone been able to resolve this issue. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and that reason was incompatibility between Coldfusion and some configurations of ASP.NET applications when IIS App pool is in integrated mode.  Coldfusion must be disable .